# HikariDataSource close

Tags: java, hikaricp

I have implemented HikariCP which is working fine and I'm now planning to do a graceful shutdown of my application and I would like to make HikariCP close the database connection properly and not just killing the java application.
I was reading on google and I could see the HikariDataSource should have a close method.... but in fact I'm not able to see it available:

```
private static DataSoure ds;
:
public blabla() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbc(jdbcURL);
    :
    ds = new HikariDataSource(config)
```

In Eclipse, if I tried ds.close()... Eclipse does not showing "close" as a valid method for HikariDataSource:

[image]

Am i doing something wrong? Probabily.... Any idea on how to make HikariCP to close properly the database connection?

Thanks,
Helio

Comment: `close()` is a [valid method](http://static.javadoc.io/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.3/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.html#close--) on `HikariDataSource`, so that should be fine. What version are you using, and are you definitely importing the correct class? (As an aside, it's autocloseable, so you should also be able to more neatly wrap it in a try with resources statement.)

Comment: Hi @MichaelBerry... I was using 2.7.8 and then I changed to 3.2.0. Both does not show me as a valid method... really not understanding... :-(   I have updated the text and added a picture of Eclipse when I tried to select a method close().... you can see it's not come as an option for me....

Comment: Doh, I completely missed your field definition in your code snippet - the answer is correct, you need to declare your field type as `HikariDataSource` rather than `DataSource`. Teaches me for looking at programming questions when I should be asleep!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerry :-)   I should be asleep to, because I don't know why i did that....

Answer (score 4):

You declare `ds` as `javax.sql.DataSource` and assign it with `HikariDataSource`. This way you will not have access to `HikariDataSource` native method.

```
((HikariDataSource)ds).close();
```

would do the trick.

Comment: ..or just declare the type of the `ds` field as `HikariDataSource` to start with of course.

Comment: yeap! You are completely right! Not sure why i did that :(  Thank you very much!

Comment: Man, you are a savior.